# How to use Scanner as a pause?

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a program that is meant to run through loops uninterrupted, with a user option to pause at any time. I want to use Scanner as a means for the user to input what they want to do to pause the program, but instead the program pauses every time it loops through, and the user is forced to input something before the code continues. My code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
     String pause = scan.next()
     {
           if (pause.equals("pause")
           {
              //break mechanism
           }
      }
  }
```

Any ideas for how I could use this with a temporary pause? I was thinking maybe it could be something like "if 3 seconds pass, continue" but I'm not sure that would work, or how to code it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit, why you want to do that

Comment: [Java input without pausing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504641/java-input-without-pausing) this can help i guess :)

Answer (score 0):

what I understood is this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WorkerThread workerThread = new WorkerThread();
        PausingThread pausingThread = new PausingThread(workerThread);
        workerThread.start();
        pausingThread.start();
    }
}

class WorkerThread extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true)
        {
            //Your work is being done
        }
    }
}

class PausingThread extends Thread{
    WorkerThread workerThread;

    PausingThread(WorkerThread thread){
        this.workerThread = thread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scan.next().equals("pause")){
            try {
                System.out.println("workerThread sleeping");
                workerThread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this will work...

Comment: if the user keys pause, the program does not stop, because the loop is continues

Comment: you mean if the user writes **pause** the program is not stopping

Comment: @Deepak Jasawat I do want it to pause, but only some times. I would like the program to run continuously unless I input "pause". A real life example: watching TV. The way my code works now, it would be like the TV pausing every second until I unpause. I want it to be like the TV running on it's own until I decide to hit the pause button. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Deepak Jasawat  only needs a break

Comment: @DylanK25_ check it now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```java
while(scan.hasNext()) {

   String pause = scan.next();
   if (pause.equals("pause"))
   {
     //stop
   }

}
```

As far as i understood it, your program stops, when the for-loop is done. Now the while-loop will be done when there is no more input.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I  think that it helps you with your idea

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.generic;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author wilso
 */
public class prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            String pause = scan.next();
            if (pause.toLowerCase().equals("pause")) {
                 System.out.println("Esperando quitar el modo pause");
                 pause = scan.next();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: And how the user can stop pause mode and input again?

Comment: then you dont need to end the loop, you can add in the break tne next   pause = scan.next();